# Permanently disable git tag version for npm version

Tags: git, npm

When running the command "npm version" you can provide a --no-git-tag-version flag to stop tags from being generated and committed. Is there a way to make this the default behavior so I don't have to remember to type --no-git-tag-version every time?

Comment: create an alias for your shell?

Comment: That probably would work for me but I was hoping for a solution that I can apply to the package.json or something so that it would be shared with my team so others don't accidentally call version without the flag.

Comment: If you are willing to share an `.npmrc` file between the teem, you can set this specific variable as false there. See the edited answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind that is relatively easy to do is make an alias for this specific command. Something like

```
alias npm-nt="npm version --no-git-tag-version" # npm version no tag
```

Then just call `npm-nt` instead of `npm version --no-git-tag-version`.

---

*Edit* - given the comment about that this configuration should be shared with others, an option is to set this flag to false through `npm config`

By the [docs of npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#git-tag-version) it's stated that this flag is true by default.

This in a project specific `.npmrc` file this can be set to false and can look something like

```
# in .npmrc
git-tag-version=false
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use,

```bash
npm config set git-tag-version false
```

to stop `npm version` permanently from creating tags and commits for npm version updates.

Note: This will be affected globally.